# best way to consolidate data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three select statements which have the bulk of their columns which are the same except a few. So here is an example

```
select
*orgid='0'
,'P' as OrgType*
, Lang
,*cast(Null as varchar) as BoardName
,cast(Null as varchar) as SchoolName*

,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column1
,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column2
,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column3

FROM *TABLEA*
WHERE *[Include_All] = 1* 
Group By *[Lang]*



select
orgid=boardname
,'B' as OrgType
, Lang
, BoardName
,cast(Null as varchar) as SchoolName


,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column1
,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column2
,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column3
FROM TABLEB
WHERE [Include_Board] = 1 
Group By [Lang], BoardName


select
orgid=SchoolName
,'S' as OrgType
, Lang
, BoardName
,SchoolName

,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column1
,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column2
,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column3

FROM TABLEC
WHERE [Include_School] = 1 
Group By [Lang], BoardName
```

So as you can see, the calculated columns are the same in each "grouping". The problem is that I have about 70 calculated fields (which are the same) in all three select statements. This makes reading the script horrible as i have to endlessly scroll.

The main changes are the first couple of columns in the select statement and then the way it groups by at the end.

Right now my current solution is to set strings and execute them. IE, I'll have

```
header1 = "SELECT FROM all..." 
header2 = "SELECT FROM board.."
header3 = "SELECT FROM school.."
footer1 = "GROUP BY lang"
footer2 = "GROUP BY lang, board"
footer3 = "GROUP BY lang, school" 
Common = CalculatedFields

EXECUTE (header1 + common + footer1)
EXECUTE (header2 + common + footer2)
```

but this just makes my script all red because its one large string. Not only that I have to break it up into different strings because I have a lot of text.

Any ideas on how to best do this while maintaining readability and clarity?

Comment: Are these: `WHERE [Include_Board] = 1` all the same?  I mean the right-hand side is always 1?  And what do those asterisks mean?

Comment: The right side is one. THe left side is dynamic. Ie, `include_all`, `include_school` and `include_baord`

Comment: I may see it too simple (or too complicated), but why cannot you define three views (one for each query)?  Then your script would look like `SELECT * FROM view_A;` three times.

Comment: Because if there is a change (lets say the spec changes in one of the "sum" columns) then I have to change it three times which is error prone. Espeically when you have about 100 calculated fields.

Comment: Well, I would say then that you should keep you definition outside your query, and 'include' it somehow (say from a table - OK, it sounds awful, I admit).

Comment: Yeah I was afraid it would come to that. I really wish `ROLL UP ` was better implemented. I tried it but I have to do so much additional work to get the rows I dont need filtered out. Not to mention that so many fields rely on what is being grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CROSS APPLY (or perhaps OUTER APPLY)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to replace the case statement in your aggregates like this:

```
with f as (
    select * from ( values
         (1,4,1,0,0)
        ,(1,5,0,1,0)
        ,(1,6,0,0,1)
    )f(IncludeColumn,SecondInclude,Column1,Column2,Column3)
)

select
  orgid=boardname
  ,'B' as OrgType
  , Lang
  , BoardName
  ,cast(Null as varchar) as SchoolName

  ,SUM(Column1) as Column1
  ,SUM(Column2) as Column2
  ,SUM(Column3) as Column3

FROM TABLEB
CROSS APPLY f
WHERE [Include_Board] = 1 
  AND Table.IncludeColumn  = f.IncludeColumn
  AND TableB.SecondInclude = f.SecondInclude
Group By [Lang], BoardName
```

where now the table f can (as appropriate) be:

- a permanent table in your database; or
- a temporary table defined by the application; or
- a table variable created within the stored procedure

This has the additional advantage of being data-driven; in the case that your masking needs to be amended, only a data change is required instead of a code change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is... the three views solution sounds best.
If consistency is your problem with that then automate the creation of the views.
Use a function to return the common "logic"

```
Create function fn_GetStaticViewElement()
   return CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),',SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column1,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column2,SUM(CASE WHEN IncludeColumn = 1 AND SecondInclude IN(4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Column3')

Create proc proc_GenerateViews

'ALTER VIEW vwALL
execSQL ('ALTER VIEW vwALL AS Select ... ' + fnGetStaticViewElement() + '...From...Where...')
'ALTER VIEW Board
execSQL ('ALTER VIEW vwBoard AS Select ... ' + fnGetStaticViewElement() + '...From... Where...')
'ALTER VIEW School
execSQL ('ALTER VIEW vwSchool AS Select ... ' + fnGetStaticViewElement() + '...From... Where...')
```

to have the data combined:
Create 1 huge view, union all the sources, combining all the possible columns.
De-normalised.
Expose sourcename into a column.
use that as part of your filter.
Should act like a partitioned view, I think.